# How to convert an int so as to return the string which is how we say the int

Tags: java, string, int

I came across this interview question where the interviewer asked to write a function which will take an integer, say 123, and will return a string that would be how one would say that integer.In above case output should be "one hundred and twenty three".I have no idea how to solve these problems.Can anyone help in how to work out this problem? A pseudo code will be helpfull.

Comment: Now that the interview is done take some time to site back and _think_ how you might approach the problem.  Ask a question if you face problems in your approach.

Comment: Have an array of these words and do some more things and you're done.

Comment: divide and rule policy might help..;)

Comment: A hashmap with (numberValue,stringValue) will help.. You also need to find the length of the number (number of digits) to append " and " .

Comment: @devnull interview is not done.I just came across this question while prepairing for interview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Code for Converting Numbers to Word  Source [here](http://way2java.com/arrays/converting-numbers-to-words/)

```
 public class YourNumberMyWord { 
        public void pw(int n,String ch) { 
            String one[]={" "," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," " +
                    "six"," seven"," eight"," Nine"," ten"," eleven"," twelve"," " +
                            "thirteen"," fourteen","fifteen"," sixteen"," seventeen"," eighteen"," nineteen"}; 

            String ten[]={" "," "," twenty"," thirty"," forty"," fifty"," sixty","seventy"," eighty"," ninety"};   
            if(n>19) { 
                System.out.print(ten[n/10]+" "+one[n%10]);
            } 
            else { 
                System.out.print(one[n]);} if(n>0)System.out.print(ch); 
                } 

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int n=0; Scanner scanf = new Scanner(System.in); 
            System.out.println("Enter an integer number: "); 
            n = scanf.nextInt();

            if(n<=0) 
                System.out.println("Enter numbers greater than 0"); 
            else { 
                YourNumberMyWord a = new YourNumberMyWord(); 
                a.pw((n/1000000000)," Hundred"); a.pw((n/10000000)%100," crore"); 
                a.pw(((n/100000)%100)," lakh"); a.pw(((n/1000)%100)," thousand"); 
                a.pw(((n/100)%10)," hundred"); a.pw((n%100)," "); 
            }
            }

    }
```

Comment: Narayan your code seems to work correct but I am having difficulty in understanding the working of it.Can you illustrate the process a bit?

Comment: Narayan like I  said, if you could explain the process a bit it will be helpfull for me to understand it.

Comment: @Namdi Narayan you dont seem to be visible on chat

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution to your problem:

[Numbers to words](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html)

It is not as simple as you may imagine.

Answer (score 0):

Use the same convertLessThanOneThousand function written earlier.

```
private static String pronounce(int number) {
            String result = "";
            int cnt = 0;
            while (number != 0) {
                int rem = number % 1000;
                result = convertLessThanOneThousand(rem) + result;
                number = number / 1000;
                cnt++;
                if (number != 0) {
                    switch (cnt) {
                    case 1:
                        result = " thousand " + result;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        result = " million " + result;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        result = " billion " + result;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code of converting an int to its English words. Hope it helps.

```
public class Excercise1 {

    static String words[]={"One","Two","Three","Four","Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten"};

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String inputValue = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a value");

        int num = Integer.parseInt(inputValue.toString());
        if(num <= 10){
            System.out.println(words[num-1]);
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must put number 1 - 10", "alert",  JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score -5):

there are number of ways..as of now

1.String.valueOf(intVarable)

2.Integer.toString(intVarable)

```
public class ConvertIntToString {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int aInt = 1;

    String aString = Integer.toString(aInt);

  }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed the fact that it was a verbal string representation, not digits..